# how do i find the total size of BTRFS snapshots

Tags: filesystem, btrfs, snapshot

I have a btrfs volume /shares that is snapshotted daily into /.snapshot folder.

I need to find out the real disk use of my /.snapshot folder. Currently it seems misleading becasue it lists each snapshot as the full size of the volume snapshotted. I believe that most of this 'size' is referenced files and not the real disk space occupied.

Is there a way I can find the actual size on disk of the entire snapshot folder?

thank you.

edit..

i think i might have found it, but as im very green on unix it would be good if someone with more knowlegde can verify for me

btrfs filesystem du -s --kbytes /.snapshots/

gives

> Total   **Exclusive**  Set shared  Filename
>
> 353.24GiB   **201.81MiB**    58.94GiB  /.snapshots

i think the answer to the actual space on disk for the /.snapshot volume is 201.81MB, but not 100% sure.

Comment: You have 201.81MiB of data referenced by only one file inside your snapshot (typically, new data), and 58.94GiB of data shared by different files inside your snapshot (files copied with --reflink), or with other subvolumes in your filesystem (e.g. already present in prior snapshots).

Comment: So, if you delete your snapshot, you will save 201MiB on your disk, plus the part of the 58GiB that are not shared outside the snapshot. If you send | receive your snapshot to an other volume (without using the -p or -c options), it will occupy 201MiB + 58GiB (because shared data inside that subvolume will be preserved). But if you copy the data of the snaphot to an other filesystem, it will occupy 353.24GiB (all data will be unshared, even if the target is btrfs too).

Answer (score 0):

finally found the answer (bash script), you need to have quota's enabled, then run.

```
str=$(sudo btrfs qgroup show /snapshottedfolder --kbytes   | tail -n +3);


string="${str//$'\n'/,}"

snapshotFolderSize=0;

while read line; do
  FIELDS=( $line )
  thisLineKb="${FIELDS[2]/'.00KiB'/''}";
  snapshotFolderSize=$((snapshotFolderSize+thisLineKb));
done <<< "$str"


echo "snapshot folder size - $snapshotFolderSize KiB";
```